# Js table, adding multiple td to a tr with data

Tags: javascript

Hi i'am trying to make a simple exercise for my self but i can't find a solution for my project.

i'm trying to place my input value's in a table with a counting number. 
the problem is that i want to create 5 "td" in my created "tr" but i only can add one.

Is there some one that knows the best way to achieve this?

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var removeRowBtn = document.getElementById("removeRowBtn");
var tableNr = document.getElementById("tableNr");

// input fields Variable
var firstName = document.myForm.firstName.value;
var lastName = document.myForm.lastName.value;
var Age  = document.myForm.Age.value;
var Country = document.myForm.Country.value;

btn.onclick = function(){ addData()};

// this function is checking if the input fields have the recuired data in it other wise it give's a error.
function validate() {
    // first name field check + error
     if( document.myForm.firstName.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your first name!" );
        document.myForm.firstName.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     // last name field check + error message
     if( document.myForm.lastName.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your last name!" );
        document.myForm.lastName.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     // age field check + error message
     if(  isNaN(document.myForm.Age.value) || document.myForm.Age.value < 1 || document.myForm.Age.value > 100 ){
        alert( "Please provide your age!");
        return false;
     }
     // country select list check + error message
     if( document.myForm.Country.value == "chooseCountry" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your country!" );
        return false;
     }
     // if evry thing is true return a value of true
       return true;
}


function addData() {

  if( validate() ){
    // creating a new tr 
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    // create a new td
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    
    // adding the created elements to a object with a class name
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(td).classList.add("numberOutput");
    tr.appendChild(td).classList.add("firstNameOutput");
    tr.appendChild(td).classList.add("lastNameOutput");
    tr.appendChild(td).classList.add("ageOutput");
    tr.appendChild(td).classList.add("countryOutput");


  }

}
```

```css
body{
  background: white;
}
img{
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 2px;

  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 8vh;

  background: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px darkgray;
}


table{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}





/* Button */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 1em 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% ;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #0c84e4;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #063e6b;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}
.btn.red{
  background:red;
  width: 100%;
}


/* input field style's */

input[type=text] {
    width: calc(25% - 8px);
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 5px;
    margin: 8px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #536DFE;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
}
input:focus{
  outline: none;
  color: black;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color:black;
  font: helvetica 12px bold ;
  text-align: center;
}

select{
  width: calc(25% - 8px);
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 5px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #536DFE;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  height: 39px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Inzend Opgave H5</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- style sheets -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section class="container">
            <form id="personInfo" name="myForm">
                <table>
                  <tbody id="table">
                      <tr>
                        <td>nr.</td>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>Country</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName">
                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
                <input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age">
                <select name="Country">
                  <option value="choose a country">Kies een land</option>
                  <option value="Nederland">NL</option>
                  <option value="Belgie">BE</option>
                  <option value="Duitsland">DE</option>
                </select>

                <input type="button" name="button" id="btn" class="btn" value="Add the input fields to the table">
               <p>To remove a table number fill in the input field with the <br> number of the table and click remove table row</p>
                <input type="button" name="button" id="removeRowBtn" class="btn" value="remove table row" style="width: 75%;">
                <input type="text" name="TableNr" id="tableNr" placeholder="table nr.">

            </form>
      </section>
    </div>



  <!-- java-scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var cw = $('.container').width();
      $('.container').css({
          'height': cw + 'px'
      });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're only calling `document.createElement("td");` once.

Comment: `var $tr = $('<tr>'); $.each(["numberOutput","firstNameOutput","lastNameOutput","ageOutput","countryOutput"],function(cls) {
      $tr.append(
        $("<td/>",{"class":cls})
      )
    });
    $('#table').append($tr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same td all the time...

try this:

```
function addData() {

  if( validate() ){
    // creating a new tr 
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    // adding the created elements to a object with a class name
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).classList.add("numberOutput");
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).classList.add("firstNameOutput");
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).classList.add("lastNameOutput");
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).classList.add("ageOutput");
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).classList.add("countryOutput");


  }

}
```

Comment: yes this works fine but i was hoping there was a slicker way i find this a little bit messy. But your right it works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: The slicker way is using jQuery now you have it